# What factors require reading אל as a preposition rather than a noun in the phrase אל־האלהים in Genesis 17:18?

Tags: hebrew

> And Abraham said **to God**, “Oh that Ishmael might live before you!” (Genesis 17:18 ESV)
> ויאמר אברהם **אל־האלהים** לו ישמעאל יחיה לפניך

The phrase אל־האלהים treats אל as a preposition: Abraham spoke "to" God (*Elohim*). However, it is obvious "to" whom Abraham is speaking and the preposition אל is unnecessary:

> And Abraham said "*HaElohim*, Oh that Ishmael might live before you!”
> ויאמר אברהם האלהים לו ישמעאל יחיה לפניך

The unmarked אל is also a noun meaning "God," which is is how God identifies Himself:

> When Abram was ninety-nine years old the LORD appeared to Abram and said to him, “I am **God Almighty**; walk before me, and be blameless (17:1)
> ויהי אברם בן־תשעים שנה ותשע שנים וירא יהוה **אל־אברם** ויאמר אליו אני־אל שדי התהלך לפני והיה תמים

Obviously, if Abraham had used אל־אברם then his request would have been understood as, *"El Shaddai, Oh that Ishmael might live before you!”*

What factors require אל to be read as the preposition and prevent Abraham from addressing God as *El, HaElohim*"

> *And Abraham said, "El, HaElohim, Oh that Ishmael might live before you!”*

Comment: Segol Alef אֶ is used when אֶל serves as a preposition.

Comment: @חִידָה Is that in the original or an addition in the Masoretic text?

Comment: Masoretes used the Segol as a pointer [>] when אל points אֶל towards someone אֶל into something.

Comment: @חִידָה My question is on the words spoken by Abraham, not the MT conventions or how the MT interprets them. Obviously the additions in the MT bring clarity to those texts which in the unpointed state can give rise to more than one reading. But they are additions not present in the original,

Answer (score 2):

There are a few grammatical and contextual factors that indicate "אל" should be read as a preposition ("to") rather than a noun ("God") in Genesis 17:18. To cut the long story short:

- The form - The noun "El" meaning "God" is generally used alone or in construct chains like "El Shaddai." "אל־האלהים" uses the preposition "אל" plus the definite noun "האלהים". This construction signals direction/relation, not appellation.
- Definiteness - "האלהים" is definite ("the God"), which would be awkward apposition after using "El" as a vocative. The preposition makes more sense grammatically.
- Parallelism - Abraham consistently uses prepositional phrases like "to the LORD" when speaking to God throughout this passage. Using "El" as direct address would break the pattern.
- Context - Abraham is making a request "to" the God he has been conversing with. Directly addressing God as "El" would be redundant rather than clarifying.
- Consistency in translation - This phrase is widely translated as "to God" by Hebrew experts, indicating the preposition reading has strong support.

So in summary, the grammar, definiteness, parallelism, flow of conversation, and scholarly consensus all point to "אל" being intended as the preposition "to" directing Abraham's plea toward the LORD God, not appellating God as El. The context requires translating it as "to God."

Answer (score 0):

All the Hebraists agree that the corpus of Hebrew texts we have today at our disposal does not reflect **exactly** the own-hand writer’s (Moses, traditionally) text. Right to try to reconstruct the original text we may utilize various methods included in what is called ‘**textual criticism**’, as well as the powerful factor of the context (not only the micro-context, but the global Bible context, too). Moreover, to reconstruct rightly the Scripture’s text, **we cannot neglect the cross-comparison between ancient Scripture’s texts and versions** (espec. Jewish ones).

As regards the passage at issue (Gen 17:18) – on the basis of the principles exposed above – is hardly to believe that the Hebrew vocabulary’s compiler(s) minted the same term אל (al) to indicate – throughout the entire Scripture - two different words, even of different classes (preposition, noun), too. To be precise, we may add that אל (al) may be used to form a negative compound (as in Pro 12:28, ‘not-death’ > ‘there is no death’). אל is – in the Tanakh - also (although rarely) an abbreviation of the term אלה, ‘these’ (a).

We may safely conclude that **the original terms indicating concepts of ‘to, towards’ (a preposition) on one hand, and ‘God’ (a noun) on the other, had – in their original wording - differents forms each one**. So, in the original texts, there wasn’t any difficult to distinguish between those two terms, because they were differently written/spoken.

Interestingly, Gesenius’ Hebrew Grammar supposed that the foregoing (in a diachronically sense) ‘step’ before the wording אל (as a preposition , ‘towards’), was אלי (b). From their part, both Davidson and Parkhurst (c) supposed that אל (as a noun, ‘God’, ‘god’), had אלה as its previous diachronically ‘step’.

**You see now – pellucidly - how in those previous eras (according these linguistic hypothesis), even only the slightly-different terms אלי (‘towards’) and אלה (‘God’, ‘god’), cannot got into a muddle**.

Regrettably, a great number of other Hebrew Bible terms have suffered this bad treatment. For a single example, we may cite the Bible Hebrew term ערב (orb), that can be translated in many ways (to mingle, a crow, a kind of tree (poplar, or willow), the evening, to become dark, a gadfly, to take on/give in pledge, to be sweet/pleasing, and so on). See, also, how this single Hebrew term ranges – today – from nouns (concrete: crow, a tree, gadfly; abstract: evening) to verbs (to mingle, to become dark, to take on/give in pledge, to be sweet/pleasing, and so on).

So, we may ask ourselves, can we really believe that - originally – the Hebrew vocabulary’s compiler(s) minted the same term ערב (orb) for 8 (or more) different (among physical objects, abstract noun, verbs, and time periods) terms? You see that is greatly more probable that these 8 terms had different forms, in archaic ages, which, through what I sometimes term it ‘linguistic slovenliness’, they converged (through different ways) in the single ערב term.

Let’s get back to the point. Although there is a possibility that in Gen 17:18 Abram invoked ‘Al Aleim’, that is ‘God, the (true) God’, **is more probable that אל, in this case, had the function of a preposition, that is, ‘to’ God**. This is confirmed by the readings of the Syriac (Peshitta), the Septuagint (προς, ‘to’), as well as the renderings of the subsequent Jewish translations of this passage (for some examples, we may cite the Isaac Leeser’s *Tanakh translation* [1853]; *Genesi*, Samuel David Luzzatto [1871]; and *The Jewish Study Bible* [by the Jewish Publication Society, 2004; also the original 1917 edition]).

---

P. S. To be accurate, your (@Revelation Lad) Hebrew quote corresponding to ‘God Almighty’(as ESV translates the expression in Gen 17:1) cannot be אל-אברם (that is, ‘to Abram’, really). The correct Hebrew expression you did want quote is אל-שדי.

---

References:
a) Gesenius’ *Hebrew Grammar* – Edited and Enlarged by E. Kautzsch (2006), § 34 a.
b) ibid, §119 g.
c) *Analytical Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon*, Benjamin Davidson, 1850 (2nd edit.), on the term אלה; *Hebrew and English Lexicon* […], John Parkhurst, 1829, on the term אלה.